# Animação de texto e animação 3D

Tags: javascript, html, css

Boa tarde só meio iniciante na área de front mas acabei me deparando com um portfólio bem legal e fiquei intrigado com duas coisas com a animação do texto quando passa o mouse por cima e com a imagem 3D  direita como e possível fazer aquilo ? link https://jacekjeznach.com/about/

Comment: O efeito de texto me parece ser feito com as junções de duas bibliotecas de animação a **wow.js: https://wowjs.uk/** e a **animate.css: https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/** já o efeito de 3D na imagem me parece que é uma adaptação dos códigos do Paul Hayes que podem ser vistos **aqui: https://github.com/leandrobeandrade/paulrhayes.com-experiments**